# Visual Studio External Tools Argument problem

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

Visual studio 2005:
I am moving from post build event to using the external tools menu with a batch file.

Previously I had

```
cd "$(ProjectDir).."
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do set bdate=%%c.%%a.%%b
pkzipc -add -overwrite -dir=current "Z:\Technology\VisualStudio2005\Project Zips\$(ProjectName)_%bdate%_%username%.zip" "$(ProjectDir)*"
```

When I try to use this as an external tool it wraps "" around the projectname and adds an extra \ on SolutionDirectory (I am not sure if I want project or solution dir going forward, neither seems to be working)

The code I'm attempting to use:

```
pkzipc -add -overwrite -dir=current Z:\Technology\VisualStudio2005\Project Zips\%2\%2_%bdate%_%username%.zip %1*
```

this code doesn't work I think the first part stripping the outside "" is answered, which leaves the extra \ on the end of the projectdir variable. How can I fix that?

Comment: It appears this may not work as well as hoped, since the target directory is pointing towards the /obj folder instead of /debug. So it misses all the supporting projects of your solution. Selecting the solution file itself and running the external tools give back the Visual Studio IDE directory or the solution directory, still not the solution's target folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using a custom built .net application instead of the command line for this, since it was less complicated that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm following you (and there's no direct question), but if you have a parameter surrounded by quotes and you want to drop them, you could use another variable:

```
set THEDIR=%1
set THEDIR=%THEDIR:"=%
```

Comment: haven't tested but sounds like that helps with the one argument, what about the extra \?
My question is the code I'm attempting to use doesn't work because of these extra attachments to the data I need, and I am not familiar with dos/win batch files all that much.

Comment: This is working ok in the command prompt, but because of other reasons in my question comment, the External Tools isn't doing what I believe I would need to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also trim the last char off like this:

```
SET SOMEVAR=%SOMEVAR:~0,-1%
```

If the quotes and the \ appear in the same variable, you could do this instead:

```
SET SOMEVAR=%SOMEVAR:~1,-2%
```

Comment: is there somewhere I could reference these commands for future use? I searched for dos batch files and could not find anything this detailed/complex.

Comment: You can find the details on substrings and string replacement by running SET /?
Other excellent sources for useful tricks are CMD /? and FOR /?

Comment: This appears to be working in the cmd prompt directly, but not in a batchfile linked via external tools in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You probably setting the external tool wrong, you need to put full path to pkzipc in the *Command:* field, and put the arguments in the *Arguments:*.
Also you don't have access to script params so %1 %2 would not work, you argaument field should be then:

```
-add -overwrite -dir=current "Z:\..\$(ProjectName)_%bdate%_%username%.zip" "$(ProjectDir)*"
```

Comment: the command I have set is a batch file with this information in it, since %bdate% is not a real environment variable and would need to change daily.